# Como obtener el valor que retorna un addEventListener en Javascript

Tags: javascript, poo, dom, eventos

necesito ayuda para poder pasar unos valores aun objeto, los cuales se obtienen por medio de un prompt que se declaran dentro de una función, dicha función se pasa como parámetro al addeventlistener, estos valores necesito que se almacenen en el objeto que se declara fuera de la función, a aquí dejo el código con el cual estoy intentando buscar la solución.

```js
const persona={
  nombre: "",
  edad:"" 
}
const boton = document.querySelector("button")

const peticion = ()=>{
  persona.nombre = prompt("ingrese su nombre")
  persona.edad = parseInt(prompt("ingrese la edad"))
  }

boton.addEventListener("click", peticion)
```

agradezco mucho si alguien me puede explicar para poder entender como solucionar esta eventualidad.

Comment: *estos valores necesito que se almacenen en el objeto que se declara fuera de la función*. Eso ya ocurre en tu código, podrás verlo si pones un `console.log(persona);` al final de los prompt. ¿Cuál es el problema realmente?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, en efecto si ejecutó el consolé.log dentro de la función aparecen los valores dentro del objeto, pero si ejecutó el console.log por fuera de la función, el objeto aparece sin los valores ingresados, lo que quiero lograr es que cada vez que ingrese un nuevo valor el objeto que está declarado se modifique y al ejecutar el console.log por fuera de la función se pueda ver los valores que se han asignado.

Comment: *pero si ejecutó el console.log por fuera de la función, el objeto aparece sin los valores ingresados*. Así debe ser, porque los datos se llenan dentro de la función. Si quieres otra cosa, explica mejor qué es lo que quieres exactamente, poniendo un ejemplo. Cuando hablas de *ejecutar el console.log por fuera de la función*  debes explicar exactamente desde dónde, o a partir de qué acción o evento, y debes explicar el contexto, cómo se relacionan los eventos y acciones, etc.

Comment: Solo es un ejercicio sencillo y no existe una relación compleja en el evento, solo quiero lograr acceder a los datos que quedan almacenados en esa función cuando se hace click en el botón que dispara el evento, un ejemplo en el que lo quiero utilizar es  creando un segundo objeto persona y sumar los dos valores edad de los objetos e imprimir en un alert el resultado de la suma

Comment: Por más sencillo que sea, Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente y ciertas cosas dependen de acciones o eventos que ocurren en el cliente: el clic de un botón, el cambio de un input, la apertura de una ventana, etc. A eso me refiero. Debes exponer un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable en el que digas: cuando ocurra esto quiero esto y cuando ocurra esto otro quiero esta otra cosa. Sin ese contexto es difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Para darte una idea, tendrías que crear un array de objetos `persona` que irías llenando en cada clic del botón y quizá poner otro botón `sumar` donde accedes al array de personas y sumas su edad. Todo ese contexto falta en tu pregunta. Haz un intento de solución y si te bloqueas en algo te ayudaremos.

Comment: En verdad te agradezco muchísimo por la disposición a ayudarme, intentaré lo que me dices y veré como me va, si no logro solucionarlo, te escribiré nuevamente.

Comment: No se resuelve esto con closures?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código actual es correcto, cumple con los requisitos que mencionas:

- Pasar unos valores a un objeto, se obtienen por medio de un `prompt` que se declaran dentro de una función
- Dicha función se pasa como parámetro al `addeventlistener`
- Estos valores necesito que se almacenen en el objeto que se declara fuera de la función

Si pones un `console.log(persona)` al final del código, verás que nombre y edad están vacíos, porque aún no se ha hecho clic en el botón y, por lo tanto, no se han llenado los datos.

Lo que necesitas es una forma de ver los datos luego de que se hayan actualizado, puede ser dentro de la función donde los llenas, justo después del `prompt`, pero también puedes hacerlo en *"otro momento"*, por ejemplo, al hacer clic en otro botón.

```js
const persona = {
  nombre: "",
  edad:"" 
};

// Obtener botones por ID
const btnPeticion = document.querySelector('#btn-peticion');
const btnVista = document.querySelector('#btn-vista');

// Crear función para cada botón
const peticion = () => {
  persona.nombre = prompt("ingrese su nombre");
  persona.edad = parseInt(prompt("ingrese la edad"));
};
const vista = () => {
    console.log(persona);
}

// Asignar evento
btnPeticion.addEventListener("click", peticion);
btnVista.addEventListener("click", vista);
```

```html
<button id="btn-peticion">Ingresar datos</button>
<button id="btn-vista">Ver datos</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, tu explicación y ejemplo fueron muy útiles, me ayudaste a resolver la duda que tenía al respecto, Muchísimas gracias 